SimplesamlPHP - Could not find any default metadata entities in set [saml20-idp-hosted] for host [xxx.com : xxx.xxx/synovus/third_party/saml/public]
I've got a project which was built in 2009 on php 5 . the project is Pure vanilla / Core php project. My task was to make it work with php 8.2 . I've uploaded the project on cloudways digital ocean server.
so while updating the SimpleSAMLphp . they were using SSO . so When i downloaded and integrated the project i'm not able to configure it anymore.
I'm getting the following error when ever I try to click on the link :

SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
1 src/SimpleSAML/Error/ExceptionHandler.php:32 (SimpleSAML\Error\ExceptionHandler::customExceptionHandler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Could not find any default metadata entities in set [saml20-idp-hosted] for host [cfgroup.com : cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public]
Backtrace:
2 src/SimpleSAML/Metadata/MetaDataStorageHandler.php:228 (SimpleSAML\Metadata\MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetaDataCurrentEntityID)
1 modules/saml/src/Controller/WebBrowserSingleSignOn.php:127 (SimpleSAML\Module\saml\Controller\WebBrowserSingleSignOn::singleSignOnService)
0 public/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:23 (N/A)
I dont know what to do now here are my config files .
1- config/config.php
<?php

  $httpUtils = new \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP();

   $config = [


  'baseurlpath' => 'https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public',

2- saml20-idp-remote.php
$metadata['https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public'] = array(
'entityid' => 'https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public',
'SingleSignOnService' =>
    'https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
'SingleLogoutService' =>
    'https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',);

3- authsources.php
 'default-sp' => [
    'saml:SP',


    'entityID' => 'https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public/saml2/idp/metadata.php',

    'idp' => 'https://cfgroup.com',

    'discoURL' => null,

    'proxymode.passAuthnContextClassRef' => false,

  
],

here are the configurations
To test the issue on Live :
https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?spentityid=federate.ipipeline.com:saml2&RelayState=https://formspipe.ipipeline.com/?GAID=7276
third_party folder contains the SimpleSAMLPHP library
https://cfgroup.com/synovus/third_party/saml/public/saml2

Is your server the SAML IdP or the SAML SP? Your configuration shows what I would expect for an SP, but the url you are testing looks like it is for an IdP

yes I want to hit the url and its and idp I'm not able to configure it properly

there are three files
1- saml20-idp-remote.php
2 - saml20-sp-remote.php
3- saml20-idp-hosted.php
i dont know where should i configure

If you are the IdP you would configure saml20-sp-remote.php with the third party service provider information and saml20-idp-hosted.php with your IdP information and configure how users should authenticate when coming to your idp in authsources.php. The docs list some ways to authenticate the users and has general setup steps.

I'm pointing to IDP ipipeline is idp and i want to login over there what should i do ?
